# Which submit button was pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/eGRRb/

have I submit buttons that are auto-generated. Each table row gets an unique ID number, and if needed each submit button can get the same unique number as well.

**Question**

The problem is that there are multiple submit buttons, so how do I know which was pressed?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table class="alerts tablesorter" id="accTable" cellspacing="0">
        <thead> 
            <tr class="header">
                <th class="activity-header"> A </th>
                <th class="activity-header"> Signed </th>
                <th class="activity-header">  </th>
            </tr>
        </thead> 

        <tbody>      

            <tr class="row" id="7249">
                <td class="activity-data">7249</td>
                <!-- tablesorter can't sort a column with check boxes out-of-the-box, so it needs something to sort on. That is why the span tag is here -->
                <!-- a jquery script is watching the state of the checkbox, so when clicked the value in the span is updated -->
                <td class="checkbox"> <span style="display:none;">0</span> <input name="signed" type="checkbox" > </td>
                <td class="edit-column"> <input value="Save" type="submit" name="7249"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="row" id="61484">
                <td class="activity-data">61484</td>
                <td class="checkbox"> <span style="display:none;">1</span> <input name="signed" type="checkbox" checked > </td>
                <td class="edit-column"> <input value="Save" type="submit" name="61484"></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accTable").tablesorter();

    // :checkbox stops from executing the event on the save button. Same as input[type=checkbox]
    $('#accTable input:checkbox').click(function() {
        // insert 1 or 0 depending of checkbox state in the tag before the input tag. In this case <span> is before <input>
        // this is done so tablesorter have something to sort on, as it doesn't support checkbox sort out of the box.
        var order = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
        $(this).prev().html(order);

        $(this).parents("table").trigger("update");
    });
});

// sends the form content to server side, and stay on page
$('form').live('submit', function() {

    alert('test');

    // don't redirect
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered many, many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form onSubmit determine which submit button was pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577469/form-onsubmit-determine-which-submit-button-was-pressed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `delegate()`:

```
$('form').delegate('input:submit','click',
                   function(){
                       alert(this.name);
                       return false;
                   });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eGRRb/7/).

---

**Edited** to address question in the comments, from OP:

> Would it be possible to display 0 or 1 as the state of the associated checkbox with this approach?

Yeah, that's possible, though it's a little more long-winded than I'd like:

```
$('form').delegate('input:submit','click',
                   function(){
                       var idString = this.name;
                       var checkboxState = $('#' + idString).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked');

                       if (checkboxState == true){
                           alert('1');
                       }
                       else {
                           alert('0');
                       }
                       return false;
                   });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eGRRb/8/).

Comment: This is also a very interesting solution! Would it be possible to display 0 or 1 as the state of the associated checkbox with this approach?

Comment: This is incredible! Thank you so much =)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an onClick handler to each button that does:

```
$(this).closest('form').data('submit_name', this.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a function to the click event of the submit buttons. That function should simply store the clicked button's value in a variable. Inside the submit event of the form, check the value of that variable. The submit event will fire after the click event so you should be able to get the expected result.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/eGRRb/6/)

The thing to note here is that that different browsers behave differently when dealing with multiple submit buttons; specially when you hit enter to submit the form. I think my example takes care of this.

Comment: That's incredible! With this solution, would it also be possible to print out the state of the associated checkbox as 0 or 1? Right now `name="signed"` for each of the checkboxes, but if needed this can of course be changed.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using one `form` and using `$('form').live('submit', function() {`  and both `submit` buttons are in the same form so its not possible in `submit` event. You have to use `click` event or two `form` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve this,

### HTML

```
<form id="my-form" ...>
    ....
    <a href="#my-form" class="btn-form-submit" data-value="save">Save</a>
    <a href="#my-form" class="btn-form-submit" data-value="save-and-add">Save and add another</a>
</form>
```

### Javascript

```
$('.btn-submit-form').on('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($form.length > 0) {
        $form.trigger('submit', {'submitBtn': $this});
    }
});


$('form').on('submit', function(ev, extra) {
    if (extra && extra.submitBtn) {
        var submitVal = extra.submitBtn.attr('data-value');
    } else {
        var submitVal = null;
    }

    // submit the form as you want with submitVal as one of the fields.
});
```

The advantage here is that your form only submits on the `submit` event and not on `click` event. This way you can have one common function to submit the form whether you click a button, hit return in a form field or submit it pragmatically.

I also like to make things as generic as possible and turn them into patterns. This two functions can work across your whole project if you come up with some patterns like naming each submit button with value as `.btn-form-submit` and having a `data-value` attribute to store the value.