# Catching the Submit works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome, firefox

I'm using this to catch the submit button press, validate everything, and then either stop it or let it go through, this works in Firefox, but not in Chrome, Chrome lets the form go through empty.  I also have a reset function that works in Chrome but in firefox.  I'm brand new to js and jquery and could use some help figuring this out since stuff working in one browswer and not in the other confuses the heck out of me :)

(Sorry about having my test alert in there still)

Here's the code:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
if (e.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.id=="btn") {

if (bizNameValid==false || bizWebValid==false || bizStreetValid==false || bizCityValid==false || bizStateValid==false || bizZipValid==false || bizPhoneValid==false || firstValid==false || lastValid==false || custStreetValid==false || custCityValid==false || custStateValid==false || custZipValid==false || custPhoneValid==false || custEmailValid==false || monValid==false || yearValid==false || typeValid==false || ccValid==false) {
alert("bizNameValid:" + bizNameValid+"\n bizWebValid:"+bizWebValid+"\n bizStreetValid"+bizStreetValid +"\n bizCityValid: "+bizCityValid+ "\n bizStateValid:"+bizStateValid+"\n bizZipValid: "+bizZipValid+"\n bizPhoneValid:"+bizPhoneValid+"\n firstValid:"+firstValid+"\n lastValid:"+lastValid+"\n custStreetValid:"+custStreetValid+"\ncustCityValid"+custCityValid+"\n custStateValid"+custStateValid+"\n custZipValid:"+custZipValid+"\n custPhoneValid"+custPhoneValid+"\n custEmailValid:"+custEmailValid+"\n monValid:"+monValid+"\n yearValid:"+yearValid +"\n ccValid:"+ccValid+" \nccType:"+typeValid);
e.preventDefault();
return false;

}
else if(total==0) {
$("#svc_desc").append("</br><label id='first_error' style='font-size:16pt;'>You must select a service to continue</label>");
alert("You must select a service to continue");
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
}
});
```

Comment: `explicitOriginalTarget` is not supported in chrome

Comment: what can I use in place of it?

Comment: do you need it at all?  Just take out the surrounding if block.

Comment: Removing it worked thanks dakait and user1389596.  Google tells me that explicitOriginalTarget only works in gecko based browsers and shouldn't be used by devs.  Google also told me to use it, so idk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    var target = e.originalEvent || e.originalTarget;

    if($(target.srcElement || target.originalTarget).attr('id')=="btn"){

    }
    //rest of  your code 


});
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8067990/1679410