# One HTML form two submit buttons - is this a limitation of jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

As far as I know the following is not possible, and if not it's a clear limitation of jquery.

I want to have an html form with two submit buttons. It is not possible to submit the form and detect which button was used to submit.

One approach is to use click(function() but by doing so you forfeit access to any fields of the form and you cannot reference the form. In fact this approach is using a link that appears to be a form but is not!

It seems to me such a basic need, how can this not be supported. Forms often have two submit options... for example "Submit" and "Edit". Either options requires a different action upon submission and user submitted form data? How can this not be possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's very possible to detect which button was used...

Comment: how so if you're detecting a form button submit, not a simple click?

Comment: If you need 2 submit buttons your UI is probably wrong. Save button would simply take input field data and save it somewhere, while Edit button would open up a new editable form where you can edit the data and then save it.

Comment: @user2056238 If you're submitting "inside" the form (e.g. pressing [Enter] in text input), the first submit button will be assumed; if you're submitting "outside" the form (e.g. using JS `form.submit()`), no button is assumed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form onSubmit determine which submit button was pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577469/form-onsubmit-determine-which-submit-button-was-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

Just an example.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post"> 
Enter a number: <input type="text" name="number" size="3"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add 10">
<input type="submit" name="subtract" value="Subtract 10"> 
</form>

<?php

// check which button was clicked
// perform calculation
if ($_POST['add'])
{
    echo $_POST['number'] . " + 10 = " . ($_POST['number']+10); 
} else if ($_POST['subtract']) {
    echo $_POST['number'] . " - 10 = " . ($_POST['number']-10); 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with two submit buttons.  But if its the data in the fields you want, based on which button was pressed, it's entirely possible to use simple logic to detect which button was clicked and then access each of the form fields by ID using jQuery.

```
$('#btn1').click(function() { $('#field1').doSomething() });
$('#btn2').click(function() { $('#field1').doSomething() });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test on my server:

```
<form method="POST" action="/test/post.php" target="_blank" id="form">
    <input type="search" name="q" value="WTF" />
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Search" />
    <input type="submit" name="b2" value="Find" />
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="id('form').submit();">Go</button>
```

The `post.php` is simply a `print_r($_POST);`. The result is as follow:

- Press `Search`:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [q] => WTF
      [b1] => Search
  )
  ```
- Press `Find`:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [q] => WTF
      [b2] => Find
  )
  ```
- Press `[Enter]` in `<input type="search">`:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [q] => WTF
      [b1] => Search
  )
  ```
- Use the `<button>` outside:

  ```
  Array
  (
      [q] => WTF
  )
  ```