# How to get clicked submit button when submitting a form via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I have a form with 2 submit buttons.

```
<form class="myForm">
     <!-- Some Inputs Here -->
     <input type="submit" name="firstSubmit" value="first submit" />
     <input type="submit" name="secondSubmit" value="second submit" />
</form>
```

I am submitting this form via JQuery.

```
$(".myForm").submit(function(){
      var submitButton = ? //I need to catch the submit button that was clicked
});
```

How can I know which submit button was clicked?

Comment: looks exactly like    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577469/form-onsubmit-determine-which-submit-button-was-pressed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721724/jquery-how-to-get-which-button-was-clicked-upon-form-submission

The answer to this is the top answer on the thread linked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(){
      $('.myForm').data('button', this.name);
});

$(".myForm").on('submit', function(){
  var submitButton = $(this).data('button') || $('input[type="submit"]').get(0).name;
});
```

Comment: Using `.submit()` is a must, anyway to get the submitted button when using it?

Comment: @AliBassam - Sure, just store the clicked button in data().

Comment: This is far better than the alternatives I've seen, and this even defaults to the first button's name if the enter key is pressed.  Although really, this should be using/submitting the button's value, not its name.

Answer (score 7):

There is now a standard `submitter` property in the submit event.
Already implemented in firefox!

```js
document.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    console.log(e.submitter)
})
```

in jQuery you just write

```js
$(".myForm").on('submit', function(e){
  e.originalEvent.submitter
});
```

for browsers not supporting it use this polyfill:

```js
!function(){
    var lastBtn = null
    document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        if (!e.target.closest) return;
        lastBtn = e.target.closest('button, input[type=submit]');
    }, true);
    document.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
        if (e.submitter) return;
        var canditates = [document.activeElement, lastBtn];
        for (var i=0; i < canditates.length; i++) {
            var candidate = canditates[i];
            if (!candidate) continue;
            if (!candidate.form) continue;
            if (!candidate.matches('button, input[type=button], input[type=image]')) continue;
            e.submitter = candidate;
            return;
        }
        e.submitter = e.target.querySelector('button, input[type=button], input[type=image]')
    }, true);
}();
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$(".myForm").submit(function(){
      var submitButton = $(":focus", this);
});
```

Comment: Hi Marcos, thank you for your contribution. In order to give more support to your answer, I would suggest you to explain a little bit better the line of thought behind your proposed solution