# How can I pop up a message box according to the button-clicked condition?

Tags: javascript

There is a form containing two buttons. And then I suppose that when I click different buttons, a relevant message box will be popped up. Once the button is clicked, it will trigger a further action called "Approval".

However, at the current situation, the alert box only shows one status. I know the current status are getting the same ID and it is a wrong operation. But I don't know the solution now. Could anyone help me?

I looked into this ref: [Form onSubmit determine which submit button was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577469/form-onsubmit-determine-which-submit-button-was-pressed), but could not quite understand the concept the solution provided.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

function ConfirmOnDelete() {

    var a = document.getElementById('a_action').value; //I want to change this
    if (a == "Approve")
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to approve?") == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete?") == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
</script>
<form id="Batch" action="Approval" method="post" onsubmit="return ConfirmOnDelete();">      
        @<text>               


            @If ViewBag.unapprovedCount > 0 Then
                @<div style="float: left;">
                    <br />                       
                    <input type="hidden" name="batch_action" value="Delete" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="a_action" name="additional_action" value="Delete" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit4" name="submit" class="button" value="Delete" style="width:100px;">
                </div>
            End If


            @If ViewBag.unapprovedCount > 0 Then                
                @<div style="float: right;">
                    <br />                       
                    <input type="hidden" name="batch_action" value="Approve" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="a_action2" name="additional_action" value="Approve" />
                    <input type="submit" id="submit3" name="submit" class="button" value="@ViewBag.batch_action" style="width:100px;">
                </div>
            End If

        </text>        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

notice the addition of `{` and `}`in your code. that's the correct syntax for javascript if statement.

**UPDATE**

you want to call the `ConfirmOnDelete()`depending on which button the from was submitted with, either the approve or delete. forgive me for using jquery

```js
$("#Batch").on("submit", function() { 
    // Does the element have focus:
    var hasApproveFocus = $("input[id='submit3']").is(':focus');
    var hasDeleteFocus = $("input[id='submit4']").is(':focus');

  //checking which of the submit button has focus to determine which was click on submit
  if (hasApproveFocus == true) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure to approve?") == true) {
      return true;
    }  else {
      return false;
    }
  } else if (hasDeleteFocus == true){
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete?") == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Batch" action="Approval" method="post">

  <div style="float: left;">
    <input type="submit" id="submit4" name="submit" class="button" value="Delete" style="width:100px;">
  </div>

  <div style="float: right;">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit3" name="submit" class="button"  value="Approve" style="width:100px;">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the solution finally. Please check.

Comment: where should i check, and this solution from mine???. if so please accept and vote up.

Comment: Ok I have seen it... nice. So how did you come across the solution

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are only getting one status is because 
`var a = document.getElementById('a_action').value; //get by Button click`
retrieves the value based on ID. ID should be unique, but both of your inputs have the id `a_action`. So the `getElementById` only returns the first value, in this case that is `Delete`.

What you can do is the following

Instead of binding `ConfirmOnDelete' on the form, you can bind in on the buttons and pass the action as an argument.

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j3rvter5/1/

Comment: I know the current status are getting the same ID and it is a wrong operation. But I don't know the solution now.

Comment: I checked the first fiddle which does not work. Thanks in advance. Let me try on the second one.

Comment: The second one also fails to work which triggers an exception for my further action.

Comment: Thanks. I made the solution finally. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

On your `#a_action` element, you can add a `data-*` attribute and *do some magic*.

```
<input type="hidden" id="a_action" name="additional_action" value="Delete" data-value="Approve" />
```

Notice at the end it says `data-value="Approve"`. Now you can grab that value like this:

```
var a = document.getElementById('a_action').getAttribute('data-value');
```

And check if the value is equal to something, just like in your example.

```
if (a == "Approve") {
    //This would be true in this example, as data-value == "Approve"
}
```

Was this was you were looking for?

Comment: @Tleung Yes, because the `data-value` attribute is set to "Approve". I don't know how your code is supposed to work, because you never included which language that is. `@If ViewBag.unapprovedCount > 0 Then` is not Javascript.

Comment: @Tleung To my understanding, only ONE button is viewed on the page, right? You cannot refer to more than one ID, as it will always take the first. If there are two buttons, always use a class rather than an ID, because classes are *one to many* and IDs are *one*, so you can only have one ID.

Comment: @Tleung If you cannot explain to me how it's supposed to work, then unfortunately I cannot help you. What happens if you click the first button and what happens if you click the second?

Comment: I suppose two buttons could have its own event. According to your solution, adding the data-value attribute does not change the button event.

Comment: @Tleung Read my comment again. I have no clue what your program should do, so I cannot help you further. It's very vague right now.

Comment: Thanks. I made the solution finally. Please check.

Comment: @Tleung I still don't know what you want, so yeah.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I achieved.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function question_submit(input) {

    if (input == 1)
    {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
            document.getElementById("action").value = "Delete";

            $('#Batch').submit();
        }
        else {
            alert('You have not submitted this form');
        }
    }
    else {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to approve?')) {
            document.getElementById("action").value = "Approve";
            $('#Batch').submit();
        }
        else {
            alert('You have not submitted this form');
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form id="Batch" name="myform" action="BatchApproval" method="post" >
    <input id="action" type="hidden" name="batch_action" /> 
    <div style="float: left;">
    <br />                      
    <input type="button" id="submit4" name="submit4" class="button" value="Delete" style="width:100px;" onclick="question_submit(1)">
                </div>

   <div style="float: right;">
   <br />                                  
   <input type="button" id="submit3" name="submit3" class="button" value="Approve" style="width:100px;" onclick="question_submit(2)">
   </div>

</form>
```