# How to select element of particular table?

Tags: jquery

I have a page made up of multiple tables with unique id's each containing a form.
How can I get the id of the table where the submit button was clicked?
I eventually want to use the id as a selector to display data in.
[See my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/8wfn2pk9/24/)

The Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.myForm').submit(function(e) {
          var data = $('table').attr('id');
          alert(data);

          e.preventDefault();

      });

  });
```

The html

```
<form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <table id="mytable1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    my table 1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="submit3">Submit

</button>
</form>
<form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <table id="mytable2">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    my table 2

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="submit3">Submit

</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form onSubmit determine which submit button was pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577469/form-onsubmit-determine-which-submit-button-was-pressed)

Comment: Having classes the same as id's and the same name on multiple elements really makes things more convoluted than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var data = $(this).find('table').attr('id')
```

(Ha. Get it? *this* should do it? I'm a laugh riot.)

this is going to give you the form that was submitted, so finding the table within it should get you want you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the `table` element is always immediately within the form, you can use the [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function. One benefit to it is it should work faster as it only traverses through elements immediately within the parent and doesn't traverse through all levels of HTML.

```
$(function() {
  $('.myForm').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var table = $(this).children('table').attr("id");

      //do something with table
  });
});
```

Otherwise, `find` as Colin suggested would definitely be the best option.

Comment: Just out of (bad?) habit, I never use 'children' but just use .find('> table') if I want to specify an immediate descendant. There's an interesting thread over here on the speed difference:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648004/what-is-fastest-children-or-find-in-jquery

If the top answer there is correct it may be faster to use find() in this case.