# How to track the initiator of the submit event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, submit

The form uses several submit buttons with different formaction. When the button is clicked, the submit event is raised. Is it possible to find out from the event handler which button was pressed?

```html
<html>
        <body>
            <form>
                <button formaction="1">1</button>
                <button formaction="2">2</button>
            </form>
            <script>
                var form = document.querySelector('form');
                form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formaction = '?';
                    alert(formaction);
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**UPD. Tested variants:**

```
event.target - <form>
event.srcElement - <form>
event.currentTarget - <form>
event.originalTarget - udefined (FF <form>)
document.activeElement - <button> (Safari <body>)
event.explicitOriginalTarget - udefined (FF <button>)
```

Comment: has Jquery answers, but you should figure it ut: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066162/how-can-i-get-the-button-that-caused-the-submit-from-the-form-submit-event or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577469/form-onsubmit-determine-which-submit-button-was-pressed

Answer (score 0):

You could add different click handlers for multiple buttons `<input type="button"/>` but if you really need to have the submit event triggered I would recommend using data tags

Add this to your input tag
`data-formaction="exampleValue"`

You can access the `exampleValue` value using: `event.target.dataset.formaction` inside your event handler

Answer (score -1):

Click events generally have two targets - `.target` which is the element that was clicked on, and `.currentTarget`, which is the element that caught the event (in this case, the form).

For your purposes, I suggest using `event.target`. A common pattern is to give your button a `name` attribute, so you can find do `event.target.name` to figure out which button was pressed.

Bear in mind this will go a bit wrong if your button contains anything complex, like an icon, because then it's the icon element will be the target.

Comment: target would be the form. (going to verify)